# How to save array value to the database instead of array key from a select option input?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, html-select, laravel-5.1

In my controller I have an array of options (`$options=['a','b','c']`) which I am using it in my view in a select input field. I need the values 'a','b','c' to be saved in the database instead of their corresponding keys (0,1,2).
How can I do this? 
Controller:

```
public function create()
    {
        $options=['a','b','c'];
        return view('example.create', compact('options'));
    }
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-4">
     {!! Form::select('option', $options ,null , ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you can show us some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the array to populate `Form::select('selected_option', $options)`, you need it to look like this:

`$options = ['a' => 'a', 'b' => 'b', 'c' => 'c'];`

Then, when the form values are passed back to the controller, `Input::get('selected_option')` will receive the value `'a'`, `'b'`, or `'c'`.

A really simple way to get the array you need is:

`$options = array_combine($options, $options);`, which will create an array with keys and values that are the same.